# Is $\sqrt {f(x)}$ infinitely differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  is an infinitely differentiable function on the whole real line and $f(x)>0$ for all $x≠0$ and $f(0)=0$ and $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ (where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $f$), and let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=\sqrt {f(x)}$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.  Is $g$ infinitely differentiable?

Actually, I did try out some examples and it is obvious that polynomials or any ordinary combinations of trigonometric functions is not going to make for a counterexample, if exists. I think counterexamples such that $g \not \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, exist.

Comment: $f^{n}(x)$ denotes the n-th derivative of the function $f(x)$ .

Comment: Not true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842143/f-be-a-smooth-function-on-real-line-f0-0-fx0-forall-x-ne-0-and